# common slice function for validation

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, string, slice

I've to check more than 10 fields and slice its value.So I wrote below common function.

```
export const sliceFunction = (e: string, limit: number) => {
  console.log(e.length > limit ? e.slice(0, limit) : '','llllllllllllllllllllllll')
  return e.length > limit ? e.slice(0, limit) : '';
};
```

and I'm calling this function to validate as shown below:

```
   const handleChange =
        (fieldName: keyof EnrollmentFields) =>
        (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
          setAlertError(false);
          if (fieldName === 'address2' || fieldName === 'address1') {
            sliceFunction(e.currentTarget.value, 55);
          }
if (fieldName === 'address3') {
            sliceFunction(e.currentTarget.value, 30);
          }
if (fieldName === 'phonumber') {
            sliceFunction(e.currentTarget.value, 14);
          }
    }
```

Issue is that console.log slices and returns correctly inside the sliceFunction. But in the input field its accepting more than the limit value. Ideally it should only accept the limit and shouldnt accept inputs after the limit.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the result returned by the function to the html input :

```
 if (fieldName === 'address2' || fieldName === 'address1') {
          e.currentTarget.value =  sliceFunction(e.currentTarget.value, 55);
          }
```

Or you can simply add `maxLength` attribute to your the html input

```
<input type="text" maxLength={5} name="address1" />
```

Comment: I tried with e.currentTarget and it didnt work. I cant use Maxlength cause I'm using customized input fields.

Comment: I changed the function toexport const sliceFunction = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, limit: number) => {
  if(e.currentTarget.value.length > limit ){
    e.currentTarget.value = e.currentTarget.value.slice(0, limit);
  } 
  return e.currentTarget.value;
}; and it worked